# Motorola 68HC12 Real Time Interrupt Registers

Tags: assembly, embedded, motorola

What does the RSWAI bit in the RTICTL register do?

Comment: Now, finally a professional question! One can think today's techies only know how to switch on/off their PC and drag/drop stuff in some editor. Welcome man!

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you've read the documentation, but in case you haven't...

> RSWAI — RTI and COP Stop While in Wait
>
> Write once in normal modes, anytime in
>   special modes. Read anytime.
>
> 0 = Allows the RTI and COP to continue
>   running in wait.
>
> 1 = Disables both the RTI and COP
>   whenever the part goes into Wait.